# SQL subquery across tables with different column names

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Say I have two tables: `orderinfo` and `customerinfo`

They look like this:

#### orderinfo:

```
OrderID
CustomerID
OrderCustomerName
OrderCustomerAddress
```

#### customerinfo:

```
CustomerID
CustomerName
CustomerAddress
```

Both `OrderID` and `CustomerID` are unique. When an order is to be created, I need to copy the info from customerinfo to orderinfo at that time as the customer may change his information later.

I hope I can just use `CustomerID`  to achieve this. How should I write the subquery? Thanks.

Comment: So you want to always retain the address used at the time of the order, allowing the customer to keep a "real" address that may be changed later without affecting the order? Just making sure I understand your intent, since it would otherwise be more standard to normalize the customer info out of the orderinfo table.

Comment: read this article on Wikipedia on [slowly changing dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension)

Comment: How is `OrderID` generated? Is it an autoincremented INT?

Comment: @NSF, great! Updated my solution which should work perfectly for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you insert a new order, you can grab a *"snapshot"* of the customer data with the following simple [**INSERT... SELECT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) query syntax:

```
INSERT INTO orderinfo (CustomerID, OrderCustomerName, OrderCustomerAddress, status) 
SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName, CustomerAddress, 'P'
FROM customerinfo
WHERE CustomerID = <customerid here>
```

This inserts a new order with the customer info at the exact time the order was placed.

This information will remain just as how it was inserted even if the customer updates his or her information in the `customerinfo` table because there aren't any cascade effects other than if the `CustomerID` changes (which it shouldn't, and even if it did change, it wouldn't change the *"snapshot"* data).

Comment: Thanks. However what if orderinfo has a column that customerinfo doesn't have: eg. orderinfo has a last column 'status' and I need to insert a constant 'P' character into that column. How should I change the query?

Comment: @NSF, just put it as a constant value in the `SELECT` statement. See my edited answer.

Comment: That helps a lot. Thanks, Zane

Answer (score 1):

To update `orderinfo` with the current values for customer name and address based on a `CustomerID`, use an `UPDATE` `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE
  orderinfo
  JOIN customerinfo ON orderinfo.CustomerID = customerinfo.CustomerID
SET 
  OrderCustomerName = CustomerName,
  OrderCustomerAddress = CustomerAddress
WHERE OrderID = <some_order_id>
```

This is useful if you want to "freeze" the customer information associated with a specific order, even if the customer later changes that information globally. If I understand correctly, that is your intent.

You can also do this with an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on the `orderinfo` table. Then you needn't execute a separate query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_order_cust_info AFTER INSERT ON orderinfo
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE
      orderinfo
      JOIN customerinfo ON orderinfo.CustomerID = customerinfo.CustomerID
    SET 
      NEW.OrderCustomerName = CustomerName,
      NEW.OrderCustomerAddress = CustomerAddress
    WHERE OrderID = NEW.OrderID
END
```

Comment: Both your answer and Zane's are very helpful. But I cannot accept both :(

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is

```
INSERT INTO orderinfo 
    (OrderID, CustomerID, OrderCustomerName, OrderCustomerAddress)
VALUES (
    '12345', 
    '789',
    (SELECT CustomerName FROM customerinfo WHERE CustomerID = '789'),
    (SELECT CustomerAddress FROM customerinfo WHERE CustomerID = '789')
)
```

But i strongly advise a change in your database structure. What you try to do violates the [Database Normalisation rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Instead, read this article on Wikipedia on [Slowly Changing Dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension) and implement it as such.

Comment: Well I think you didn't get what I meant. The customer info in the order table is not to be synchronized with the info in customer table except at the moment when an order is created. Later they could be irrelevant. Anyway still good article :)

Comment: @NSF i fully understood what you mean. That is exactly the problem which the [Slowly Changing Dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension) pattern solves: it *links* (normal forms..) your order to the customer data *at a specific point in time*. That way it is possible to retrace later where your orders have been sent to, *without violating the normal forms*.